# A few questions related to the Knesset Hagdolah and the Sanhedrin

Tags: history, golus-exile, sanhedrin

Wikipedia says the Great Assembly was established in 410 BCE, and I'm wondering if that's what the masorah teaches.  Wikipedia also mentions that Sanhedrin began to form around 57-55 BCE, and I'm also wondering if that's what the masorah teaches.   Could the Knesset Hagdolah be considered a sort of proto-Sanhedrin?  Also, were there multiple sanhedrin that eventually got merged into one centralized Sanhedrin in Jerusalem?

I'm also confused about the way religious and political leadership looked before the Great Assembly was formed.  If Cyrus let the Jews return to Jerusalem starting in 539 BCE, and the second temple was built in 516 BCE, then what was happening in between?  Furthermore, what did Jewish religious leadership in Babylon look like from the exile, leading up to the time of the Babylonian Tannaim?  Were the Babylonian Tannaim taking their Rabbinical cues from the Tannaim living in the Eretz?  Was it the other way around?

I understand this is a lot of questions, and I also understand that there are answers in history textbooks, but I'm wondering how to figure these things out within the framework of a halakhic worldview and according to the traditional Masorah?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Daniel and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!